# Email Localization

Tags: wordpress, civievent, email

I'm trying to modify the default confirmation mail for event registrations.  The sent confirmation mails are in German, but the Message-Templates I can find are all English. Where can I edit the german message templates?

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.13.

Greetings,
lagertonne

**EDIT:** It's normal, that the templates are in English. The translations are made via the {ts} tag in the templates. So obviously, the "error" is intended.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the version of CiviCRM you are using.